# Dynamic Pivot CASE WHEN got error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

```
SET @sql = NULL;
set @sql = (
                select group_concat(distinct
                concat(
                "(CASE WHEN param_code IN ('20', '43')
                THEN EXP(AVG(CASE WHEN YEAR(`res_date`) = '", YEAR(`res_date`),"'  THEN LOG(`res_value`) END))
                ELSE AVG(CASE WHEN YEAR(`res_date`) =  '", YEAR(`res_date`),"'  THEN `res_value` END)
                END) as  '",YEAR(`res_date`),"'"
                )   
                )
                from wq_results
                );
                
set @sql = concat("select station_id AS ID, tbl2.station_name, param_code, ", @sql, " from wq_results as tbl1 left join mon_stations as tbl2 on tbl1.station_id = tbl2.id  where sc_id='20' and param_code = IN (20,43) group by station_id");
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
```

tbl1 wq_results

| id | station_id | param_code | res_value | res_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 | 1,452 | 2021-12-06 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 | 85 | 2022-12-06 |
| 3 | 1 | 20 | 1,854 | 2023-01-06 |
| 4 | 1 | 43 | 67 | 2023-01-06 |
| 5 | 2 | 43 | 1,285 | 2023-12-06 |

tbl2 mon_stations

| id | station_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Station 1 |
| 2 | Station 2 |

output should be like this

| Station ID | Station Name | Parameter | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Station 1 | 20 | 1,452 | 85 | 8,254 |
| 2 | Station 2 | 43 | - | - | 1,285 |
| 1 | Station 1 | 43 | - | - | 67 |

Comment: where sc_id='20' and param_code = IN (20,43)  - remove = voting to close as typo Also where does sc_id come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

You had an error related to `group by`, you should include `tbl1.station_id, tbl2.station_name, param_code`

The where clause can be removed

```
SET @sql = NULL;
set @sql = (
            select group_concat(
                  distinct concat(
                "(CASE WHEN param_code IN ('20', '43') THEN EXP(AVG(CASE WHEN YEAR(`res_date`) = '", YEAR(`res_date`),"'  THEN LOG(`res_value`) END)) ELSE AVG(CASE WHEN YEAR(`res_date`) =  '", YEAR(`res_date`),"'  THEN `res_value` END) END) 
                 as  '",YEAR(`res_date`), "'"
                  )   
            )
            from wq_results
          );
                
set @sql = concat("select tbl1.station_id AS ID, tbl2.station_name, param_code, ", @sql, " 
                 from wq_results as tbl1 
                 left join mon_stations as tbl2 on tbl1.station_id = tbl2.id  
                 where param_code IN (20,43) 
                 group by tbl1.station_id, tbl2.station_name, param_code");
select @sql;
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/nTrweP3G)